# axios get req error can not access http only token in next js but workd fine in post main

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

hy am building an forum in next js using httponly cookie for jwt authantication but get this error
this is my auth middleware

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import createError from "http-errors";
import Cookies from "cookies";
/**
 * @param {import('next').NextApiRequest} req
 * @param {import('next').NextApiResponse} res
 */

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
  const token = cookies.get("token");
  console.log(token);
  // const { cookies } = req;
  // const token = cookies.token;

  if (!token) return next(createError("Unauthorized"));

  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT);
    req.user = user;
    console.log(req.user);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(createError("Login to gain access "));
  }
};
```

this my api to get questions posted by user

```js
import nextConnect from "next-connect";
import connect from "../../../utils/connectMongo";
import Question from "../../../models/question";
import auth from "../../../middleware/auth";
import Cookies from "cookies";
/**
 * @param {import('next').NextApiRequest} req
 * @param {import('next').NextApiResponse} res
 */
connect();
const apiRoute = nextConnect({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res.status(501).json({ error: ` ${error.message}` });
    console.log(error);
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
});
apiRoute.use(auth);
apiRoute.get(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  try {
    const { _id } = req.user;
    console.log(req.user);
    let { page, size } = req.query;
    const limit = parseInt(size);
    const skip = (page - 1) * size;
    const question = await Question.find({ user: _id })
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(skip)
      .populate("user", "name picture")
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: question,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
});
// export const config = {
//   api: {
//     bodyParser: false, // Disallow body parsing, consume as stream
//   },
// };
export default apiRoute;
```

in postman api works fine but in axios it says Unauthorized form auth middleware
my axios configs are
this is how i made req to server

```js
export async function getStaticProps(page, size) {
  const response = await instance.get(
    `${baseUrl}/api/question/userquestion`,

    { withCredentials: true }
  );
  const questions = await response.data.data;
  return {
    props: {
      questions,
    },
  };
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XTl2.jpg)

Comment: Didn't dive into the code. I would just look to the dev tools to see what exactly sent to the server: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs on the server at build time, it doesn't have access to request-specific data like cookies. If the request requires user authentication, move it to the client-side instead.